# Probability that one random number among many has a unique prime factor

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, multiplicative-function

If I sample $N+1$ integers $x, x_1, \ldots, x_N$ uniformly and independently from $\{1, \ldots, M=2^k\}$, what is the probability that $x$ contains a prime divisor that does not divide any of the $\{x_i\}$? Upper/lower bounds and/or asymptotic approximations would also be of interest.

For prime $p$ and $x, x_1, \ldots, x_N$ as above, say $x$ is $p$*-unique* if $p | x$ and $p \nmid x_1, \ldots, p \nmid x_N$. For any fixed and sufficiently small prime $p$ (say, $p \leq \sqrt{M}$), the probability that $x$ is $p$-unique is $\frac{1}{p} \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^N$. One can try to lower bound $\Pr[\vee_p \hspace{2pt} \mbox{$x$ is $p$-unique}]$ using the inclusion-exclusion principle and treating the events that $x$ is $p_1$-unique and $p_2$-unique as independent when $p_1, p_2$ are both sufficiently small (and distinct). Doing so gives a lower bound of $\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^N - \sum_{p_1 \neq p_2} \frac{1}{p_1p_2} \left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right)^N \left(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\right)^N$ (where the sums are over sufficiently small primes). But I didn't know where to go from there.

This seems like a problem that would have been studied before in the context of multiplicative number theory but I have not managed to find any references.

Comment: You need to clarify whether $x$ is fixed in the set of $N+1$ numbers or whether you are happy with any of the $x_i$ having the property as well. Also, write out your sum over the primes, we cannot read your mind.

Comment: As written, $x$ is fixed. I can write out the sum over primes I was thinking of, but it was meant to be suggestive rather than specific.

Comment: By $k$-bit integers do you mean $2^{k-1} \le x_i \lt 2^k$?

Comment: yes, that is what was intended. Though if it makes the question easier, you could choose the integers from $\{1, ..., K\}$

Comment: I feel like you've essentially written down the answer ... wouldn't it be $1 - \prod_p \bigl( 1 - \frac1p ( 1-\frac1p )^N \bigr)$?

Comment: @GregMartin That would imply the probability is $1$ since $\prod_p{\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)} = 0$. Doesn't mean it isn't correct though

Comment: Fair point, I think 1 is believable

Comment: I can also believe it tends to 1 as k goes to infinity, but I am more interested in the dependence on k (and N).

Comment: Grimms says in any set of consecuitive composites you can have all of them with a distinct prime divisor... start there ?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but even if Grimm's conjecture is true it seems to imply only a very weak bound.